# Tensorflow 2.X Error - Op type not registered 'CaseFoldUTF8' in binary running on Colab

Tags: tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model

I have been using BERT encoder from the Tensorflow hub for quite sometime now. Here are the syntaxes:

`tfhub_handle_encoder = "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_multi_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4" tfhub_handle_preprocess = "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_multi_cased_preprocess/3" bert_preprocess_model = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess)`

All off a sudden I am encountering this error message:
`FileNotFoundError: Op type not registered 'CaseFoldUTF8' in binary running on acb9309ebd87. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.)` tf.contrib.resampler`should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed. You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the`experimental_io_device`option in`tf.saved_model.LoadOptions `to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.`

The same code has been running well for years now. Tf Version - 2.9, Environment - Colab/ GCP Vertex AI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ambiguous error message is due to importing tensorflow_hub package after calling the encoder. The issue got resolved when I pushed the import statement before calling the encoder.

Answer (score 6):

Importing `import tensorflow_text as text` should solve this issue.

Edit: You might have to run `!pip install tensorflow_text` in Colab.

Answer (score 0):

2 years ago, I trained model in google colab than compressed it into a zip file

some days ago, I trained that model again (with other train data) in google colab, ran it with the same code then I encountered this error

I extracted the zip file from 2 years ago, ran it with the same code, everything is fine

so I guess, you need be sure that version of tensorflow you use to trained model is the same with it in the past